# How to change a parameter inside an object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Begginer here.

```
var player() = {
isDrunk: false
}
```

How do I set isDrunk to true after the player uses item "Beer"? (Completely made-up example)

Comment: You can read on about JavaScript object basics here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics

Answer (score 3):

To specifically answer your question you would just do something like `player.isDrunk = true`

So you could have something like

```
var player = {
  leftHanded: false,
  rightHanded: true,
  isDrunk: false
 };
```

And then

```
  function drinkBeer(player) {
      player.isDrunk = true;
 }
```

Then you can pass your players to your drinkBeer function as needed.  Alternatively you can put the function inside the player object if you want each individual player to have a `drinkBeer()` function that they can use to change their own `isDrunk` property by calling `player.drinkBeer()`

That would look like this:

```
var player = {
  leftHanded: false,
  rightHanded: true,
  isDrunk: false,
  drinkBeer: function() {
        isDrunk = true;
     }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You should google your question before you ask it because documentation for JavaScript objects is everywhere... But...

```
var player = {
  myFirstValue: true,
  mySecondValue: false
};

player.myFirstValue = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to create an object that can invoke an action to "drink" a beer. The following is the newer class syntax (ES6) which is not widely supported in older browsers, but worth a study.

```
class Player {
    constructor(){
        this.isDrunk = false;
    }

    useBeer(){
        this.isDrunk = true;
    }

    isDrunk(){
        return this.isDrunk;
    }
}

var player = new Player();
player.useBeer();
console.log(player.isDrunk()); // true
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: but the documentation says that class keyword is not supported in IE. Is it worth using?

Comment: @Prabhakaran As I mentioned in the answer, this syntax isn't widely supported in older browsers. However, pre-compiling/transpiling JavaScript is a very common/beneficial practice which would allow the use of newer syntax (code maintenance, sugar) without losing the ES5 compatibility. I would recommend learning the newer syntaxes as much as possible, since the idea is that the language is improving and modern browsers are working to support these updates.

Comment: @Prabhakaran Totally fair question though, and if code pre-compiling isn't an option on top of the requirement to support older browsers, then it wouldn't be an appropriate solution. But again, there are fantastic tools out there that open up all kinds of possibilities :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of isDrunk either using switch or if statement, anything of your choice. But before that kindly have a look at the syntax or way of creating objects.

```
  var player = {isDrunk:false, hadBeer:false}
  if (player.hadBeer) {
    player.isDrunk = true;
  } else {
    player.isDrunk = false;
  }
```